# Emoji setup in my project

Tags: android, github, emoji

I referred 
https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji

but iam getting one error.I did everything what he had said

```
final EmojiPopup emojiPopup = EmojiPopup.Builder.fromRootView(rootView).build(emojiEditText);
```

(it is below " To open the EmojiPopup execute the code above: "  line)

cannot resolve `rootView`

I'm unable to understand what is `rootview` here.

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: have you declared `rootview` in your code? Also post some code.

Answer (score 0):

The rootView is the rootView of your layout xml file which will be used for calculating the height of the keyboard. emojiEditText is the EmojiEditText that you declared in your layout xml file.

This will be a View subclass that you instantiate through inflating an xml layout.

The layout he uses in the example is [this one](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji/blob/46dcd015cce144f7bc8657c9396507e8988f60c4/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) which is inflated as follows:

```
rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_root_view);
```

**Extracted [from his own code samples](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji/blob/46dcd015cce144f7bc8657c9396507e8988f60c4/app/src/main/java/com/vanniktech/emoji/sample/MainActivity.java)**. This would be the rootView in your above example.

Comment: Thanks a lotbut i have a doubt can i add this line or not compile 'com.vanniktech:emoji:0.4.0-SNAPSHOT'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but that string is the product ID for Maven and you should be able to replace it with whatever you want as long as it is used consistently through pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

First install the emoji installer in your **splash activity** or **application class** - basically it has to be executed before your layout is inflated in onCreate in your activity.  Otherwise the layout will not recognize this `<com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiEditText />`.

```
// Init Emoji
EmojiManager.install(new IosEmojiProvider());
```

You also need a rootview as explained above by jugutier.
In your **xml file** declare the view widget like this (this is for constraint layout)

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/a_chat_v_keyboard"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="200dp"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view3"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

You can use the following in your activity class.

Declaration

```
private View vKeyboard;
```

Binding

```
vKeyboard = findViewById(R.id.a_chat_v_keyboard);
```

Then in your activity you can get the keyboard to pop up like this

```
final EmojiPopup emojiPopup = EmojiPopup.Builder.fromRootView(vKeyboard)
                                                .build(etTextMessage);

ivEmoticonToggle.setTag(1);

ivEmoticonToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        emojiPopup.toggle();

        if (ivEmoticonToggle.getTag().equals(1)) {

            ivEmoticonToggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.keyboard);
            ivEmoticonToggle.setTag(2);

        } else {

            ivEmoticonToggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.emoticon);
            ivEmoticonToggle.setTag(1);

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: where does come from etTextMessage variable?

Comment: any edit text in your activity which you have declared

Comment: If this many people have to visit SO...author of this library made it very unclear how to use in docs....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EmojiEditText in any Activity other than FirstActivity then install Emoji in the first activity using

```
EmojiManager.install(new IosEmojiProvider());
```

or if you are using this in the FirstActivity then Create a new class extended by the Application class and put this line in the onCreate method

```
EmojiManager.install(new IosEmojiProvider());
```

and put this line inside the application tag in your manifest file

```
android:name=".YourClassName"
```